# Is it efficient (in Python) to assign a thread to objects or scan the list of objects?

Tags: python, multithreading, process

I have thousands of objects of the following class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__age = 0          # the initial age of the object is 0
        self.__age_limit = 100  # the max age of the object is 100 ms
```

where I set the unit of age to 1 ms, so the maximum age of an object is 100 ms  old.

When it is coming to the point to decide if the object is 'dead', I find I am in the hard place, since I have little experience of using multi-process in Python.

My question is:

1. Shall I add a micro-process to each of the objects to find out if its parent object is dead? My concern about this method is it will exhaust the memory
   (16GB in my case) fast and kill the computer.
2. Or I should put the objects into a list and scan it every 1 ms? My
   concern about this method is it will not fast enough to 'kill' the
   objects before the object exceeds its age limit.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood the question, but probably you want to use a single thread and a [sched](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sched.html).